How could I improve the rendering of Arabic in Google Chrome?
By default, here's how Arabic text looks like in Chrome :

It's hardly readable, even after zooming 150% to 175% (and ofc, the UI becomes unusable ).
Is there a native way to improve the readability? I've tried some extensions, but they're all dying soon with the introduction of Manifest V3.. For instance, here's the same page with Wudooh :


Is the site supplying the font via CSS, or is it using the default Arabic font for Chrome?

The latter. Check out the Arabic Wikipedia to get an idea.

What I see and what you see may be two different things.  You need to check the fonts in chrome://settings/fonts and possibly set one or more of the fonts to one that has a more readable Arabic. I do not read Arabic, but I would not judge the font that I see in the Arabic Wikipedia to be of poor quality or limited readability.
